# Laravel belongsToMany not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to define a Many to Many relationship using "belongsToMany" relationship between 2 tables with a lookup table. These are my tables:

## encounter_templates (EncounterTemplate model)

- id
- template_name
- ... (more irrelevant colums)

## encounter_forms (EncounterForm model)

- id
- form_name
- ... (more irrelevant colums)

## encounter_templates_forms (EncounterTemplateForm model)

- id
- template_id
- form_id

In the EncounterTemplate model I'm trying to attach a list of forms that belong to it, so I have a forms() function with the following:

```
public function forms() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\EncounterForm', 'encounter_templates_forms', 'template_id', 'form_id');
}
```

However it returns an empty object. I can get it working by using the following instead:

```
$forms = \App\EncounterTemplateForm::where("template_id",$this->id)
    ->join("encounter_forms", "encounter_templates_forms.form_id","=","encounter_forms.id")
    ->get();

return $forms;
```

But I'm wondering what am I doing wrong with my relationship declaration. I'd prefer to do it the "proper" Laravel way if I can. Would appreciate any insight.

EDIT: If I run EncounterTemplate::find(1)->forms()->toSql() I get the following query:

```
select * from `encounter_forms` inner join `encounter_templates_forms` on `encounter_forms`.`id` = `encounter_templates_forms`.`form_id` where `encounter_templates_forms`.`template_id` = 1
```

Which returns expected results... so perhaps the issue is downstream further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So further downstream I was calling the forms() method dynamically. It turns out I needed to call a ->get() on it as well since it apparently forms() returns a query builder instance rather than a model result. For any future people interested, this is what my working code looks like:

```
$record = $model::find($id);
$include = $request->input("include");
$result_array = $record->toArray();

if ($include) {
    $includes = json_decode($include);

    foreach ($includes as $child_model) {
        $child = $record->$child_model();
        $result_array[$child_model] = $child->get(); //where $child == 'forms'
    }
}

return $record_array;
```

Thanks for the help in troubleshooting James! Your input helped me narrow down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one it works on me.

add this in your model

**EncounterTemplate model**

```
public function encounterTemplateForm()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EncounterTemplateForm::class);
    }
```

**EncounterForm model**

```
public function encounterTemplateForm()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EncounterTemplateForm::class);
    }
```

**EncounterTemplateForm model**

```
public function template()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(EncounterTemplate::class, 'template_id', 'id');
}

 public function form()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(EncounterForm::class, 'form_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your relationship is just a little off, from the docs:

> ...The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to

As such the parameters are like so:

1. The other model that you want to link to
2. The name of the table that joins these records
3. The name of the field in the joining table that references the **current** model
4. The name of the field in the joining tables that references the **foreign** model

Given you are defining this relationship on the `EncounterTemplate` model currently, the third parameter should be `template_id` and the fourth `form_id`:

```
public function forms() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\EncounterForm', 'encounter_templates_forms', 'template_id', 'form_id');
}
```

Comment: You're right the docs indicate it should be the other way, which is how I originally tried it, but unfortunately I tried both variations and neither seem to work. I've edited my post to reverse the column names (and also ran my code again with it reversed just to triple check that I'm not going crazy)... and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3246127 Try preview the SQL to see what is happening `EncounterTemplate::find(1)->forms->toSql();` this assumes you have a template of 1 that has forms.

Comment: It returns correct query and running that query raw returns the expected results, so perhaps the issue is further downstream in my project somewhere. I'll update this question when I figure it out!